# Vagrantfile: How do I pass a host environment variable with an unescaped dollar sign in it?

Tags: ruby, bash, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

If I add something like this to `Vagrantfile` in the appropriate place:

```
vm.provision "shell",
path: "my_node.sh",
env: {"MY_VARIABLE"=>ENV['CONTAINS_A_DOLLAR_SIGN']}
```

And in my `my_node.sh` I add this:

```
echo "$MY_VARIABLE"
```

If my `CONTAINS_A_DOLLAR_SIGN` environmental variable is `before$after` my `vagrant up` output will contain `before` but not `$after`.

How do I fix this in `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: Is writing the env var as `before\$after` an option?

Comment: This is likely either the Ruby interpreter or the shell interpreter resolving the `$after` as a variable with a `nil` or `null` value, both of which cast to string as `empty`. Can you explicitly set this value as a literal string and block interpolation by the interpreter? Adding Ruby tag in case the root cause is the MRI.

Comment: The value of the environmental variable cannot be changed, so I would say no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a hint from @matt-schuchard, I added this at the top of Vagrantfile:

```
require 'shellwords'
```

and changed

```
env: {"MY_VARIABLE"=>ENV['CONTAINS_A_DOLLAR_SIGN']}
```

to

```
env: {"MY_VARIABLE"=>Shellwords.escape(ENV['CONTAINS_A_DOLLAR_SIGN'])}
```

Now `vagrant up` outputs `before$after` not just `before`!